# Can not add python lib to existing Docker image on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

Good day,
I'm trying to deploy Telegram bot on AWS Ubuntu server. But I can not run application because server says (when i run docker-compose up):

```
there is no name: asyncpg
```

However I installed it manually on server through

```
 pip3 install asyncpg
```

and I checked later it is in the "packages" folder.

However, I sort of understand where problem is from. When I first tun

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

It used this file:

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8


WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /src
```

Where requirements.txt lacked this library. I edited requirements with

```
nano
```

and tried to run:

```
docker-compose up
```

again, but i again run into similar problem that

```
there is no asyncpg package
```

So as I understand docker-compose up uses already created image where there is no such package. I tried different solutions from SOF like build and > freeze but nothing helped. Probably because I dont quite understand what im doing, Im beginner at programming and python.

How can I add this package to existing docker image?

Comment: Add the package to the requirements.txt file on your host (i.e. not in the container). Then run `docker-compose build` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after you have added the library package manually on the server, to save back the changes made into the docker image you would need to commit the running docker container using the command,

`docker commit <container-id> <image-name>`

---

Let's take an example.
you have an image, `application`

you run the docker image and get back container-id say `1b390cd1dc2d`.

Now, you can go into the running container using the command -
`docker exec -it 1b390cd1dc2d /bin/bash`

Next, install the package -
`pip3 install asyncpg`

Now exit from the running container `exit`

Use the first command shared to update the image like below

`docker commit 1b390cd1dc2d application`

This updates the image by adding the required library into your image

Comment: While this might work, it's not a good idea to start modifying your images this way. One of the strengths of dockerfiles is that you have a recipe under source control, that tells how the image was built. You can then easily modify it or add to it. By using `docker commit` you lose that ability.